Error in SSIS while adding Dimention Processor
I have Windows 10 Pro with Visual Studio 2019. The server is SQL Server 2012. I build a sample project which contains just two items:

OLE DB Source
Dimention Processor

I follow the manual, but I get error, when I click on Extended Properties or try build the project:

[Dimension Processing [22]]: A required child element is missing under
Envelope/Body/Execute/Command at line 1, column 331 (namespace
'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis'). One of Statement, Create,
SetAuthContext, Alter, Delete, Process, DesignAggregations,
NotifyTableChange, UpdateCells, ClearCache, Lock, Unlock, Insert,
Update, Drop, Backup, Restore, ImageSave, ImageLoad, CloneDatabase,
MergePartitions, Subscribe, Detach, Attach, Batch, BeginTransaction,
CommitTransaction, RollbackTransaction, GetTransactionState, Cancel,
Synchronize, Import80MiningModels, InternalSynch, FileTransferQuery,
Metadata, Data, KeyColumns, NameColumn, QueryDefinition,
BeginQueryTrace, PauseQueryTrace, ResumeQueryTrace, EndQueryTrace,
GetQueryTraceInformation was expected. Error in the data flow task
[Dimension Processing [22]]: Internal error: An unexpected exception
occurred. Error in the data flow task [SSIS.Pipeline]: Dimension
Processing failed validation and returned error code 0xC10F000A

Inside the .dtsx file itself I didn't found the path: Envelope/Body/Execute/Command.
I searched for the solution, and didn't found nouthing in internet...
Here is the project itself.
UPDATE
As I can see from documentation of the namespace urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis (pages 9 and 10), Execute it is SOAP method sending from client to the server, and client sends it in format different than server expects... Need I to search and investigate the logs of SOAP interaction between client and server?
UPDATE
I tried to downgrade Visual Studio Code to 2017 version and met follow error while built and run a simmilar project:

Errors related to feature availability and configuration: The 'Data
Push' feature is not included in the '64 Bit Standard' edition of
Analysis Services.

